# WMQueryEndSessionが発生しない？

Tags: delphi

WMQueryEndSession で、widowsが終了する前の処理をしようと思いますが、WMQueryEndSessionが発生しないようで、WMQueryEndSession内の処理が実行されません。考えられる、原因をご教示ください。
開発環境
Parallels Desktop( 10.2.0 ) + Windows7 sp1 ( バージョン6.1、ビルド7601、64ビット版 ) + RAD Studio XW7( Delphi バージョン 21.0.17707.5020  )

Answer (score 1):

どういうコードを書いてみてダメだったのでしょう？
メッセージ処理自体は下記コードでWindows終了時にメッセージが来るはずです。
Hideした状態やMinimizeな状態でも実験してみましたが、ちゃんとメッセージが来てました。

追記
書いてから気付きましたが、下記はVCLの場合の話でFMXの場合は話が別ですね。

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  procedure WMQueryEndSession(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_QUERYENDSESSION;
end;

procedure TForm1.WMQueryEndSession(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_QUERYENDSESSION;
begin
  ShowMessage('a');
  Msg.Result := 1;
end;
```